# Adding a List to a List Item

Tags: html, css, html-lists, html-select

I have developed a webpage using the BootStrap framework and have a question about list items in my header.

How can I add a list to a list item?

Here is a link to my website: http://www.canninginc.co.nz/
As part of the header, I have a Products drop down list with an item 'CanLucidDream'. I am wanting to add a list (with list items) to this 'CanLucidDream' item. E.g. Galley, about etc

How can I do this?

**EDIT**

I did not explain what I am after very well. Basically, I want to have a list of items for the product CanLucidDream to the side of the CanLucidDream item. Like a menu item in a GUI forms application with a little arrow to the right of the menu item that then shows the list.

Is this possible in HTML/CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can*, but a list within a list within a list starts looking really cluttered. If that's what you want, though, than just start a new list after the "CanLucidDream" anchor:

This is what you have:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li>
<a href="canluciddream/">CanLucidDream</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

This is what it turns into:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li>
<a href="canluciddream/">CanLucidDream</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a>This is the first thing.</a></li>
    <li><a>This is the second thing.</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

You'll need to style that, of course. Bootstrap might already have some sort of styling built in for drop-downs within drop-downs.